# Do the Collector's Sets (e.g. Premium Gold) contain/equal booster packs?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Basically, I'm doing a Secret Santa and the person I'm buying for has asked for Yu-Gi-Oh booster packs. I know almost nothing about the game so I just want to get some clarification on what exactly constitutes one, so I don't buy the wrong thing. [This](http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/products/gs-premgold-2.html) is one I came across in the price range that I like the look of, but I want to be sure that this is the kind of thing he's looking for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: (Thanks for changing the title, mods. I couldn't think how to phrase it.)

Answer (score 1):

While the Premium Gold packs aren't really a booster pack in the traditional sense, they make for great gifts. You're getting much better cards for the price.

A newer product to look into would be an [Invasion: Vengeance Special Edition box](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Invasion:_Vengeance:_Special_Edition). These contain 3 boosters packs and 2 Super Rare cards.

Comment: only opposition to the answer given above, would be if a specific series of booster pack was listed.